# Updating a list of df variables after modifying a df

Tags: python, machine-learning, refresh

I have a list of predictor (X) and an outcome (y) variables from my df. There are 100s of variables in my df so I only care about a few of them below.

`X = df[['a', 'b', 'c']]`

`y = df['d']`

I then want to delete all of the rows with missing data for any of my "X" variables, so I ran this:

```
for i in X:

    df = df[df[i].notna()]
```

This then leaves me with a modified df with no missing values in the columns of interest. However, my list X and y are still populated with the old df, thus I can not use these as inputs to my model. While I know I could just copy and paste the code I used to create those lists in the first place to "refresh" the code, that seems inefficient. Though I can not seem to think of a better way. Thoughts appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`df.dropna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html):

```
X = X.dropna()
```

Comment: Thank you, and my other issue was that I also need "y" to be the same dimensions. so if I only drop from X then the two lists will be different dimensions

Comment: Okay, thank you for the heads up. I am new to the forum and am still learning the etiquette